# Solving these coupled differential equations.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I have a set of coupled differential equations of the form

$$ \omega y_1 \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial y_1}+\omega y_2 \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial y_2}+\omega y_3 \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial y_3}+g\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial y_1}+t q_{3}e^{-g/\omega (y_{3}-y_1)}-t q_{2}e^{-g/\omega (y_{2}-y_3)}=(E+g^2/\omega)q_1$$

$$ \omega y_1 \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial y_1}+\omega y_2 \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial y_2}+\omega y_3 \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial y_3}+g\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial y_2}+t q_{1}e^{-g/\omega (y_{1}-y_2)}-t q_{3}e^{-g/\omega (y_{3}-y_1)}=(E+g^2/\omega)q_2$$

$$ \omega y_1 \frac{\partial q_3}{\partial y_1}+\omega y_2 \frac{\partial q_3}{\partial y_2}+\omega y_3 \frac{\partial q_3}{\partial y_3}+g\frac{\partial q_3}{\partial y_3}+t q_{2}e^{-g/\omega (y_{2}-y_3)}-t q_{1}e^{-g/\omega (y_{1}-y_2)}=(E+g^2/\omega)q_3$$

How do I solve these multivariate coupled differential equations?

When I add all of these equations together, I obtain

$$\omega y_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}(q_1+q_2+q_3)+\omega y_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y_2}(q_1+q_2+q_3)+\omega y_3 \frac{\partial}{\partial y_3}(q_1+q_2+q_3)+g \nabla\cdot q=(E+g^2/\omega)(q_1+q_2+q_3) $$

I am very confused about how to handle the $\nabla\cdot q=\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial y_1}+\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial y_2}+\frac{\partial q_3}{\partial y_3}$ term.